# How to solve this kind of Conditional Probability problems?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a series of problems that involve events that happen one after another, and where the usual formulas like $P(\frac{A}{B})=\frac{P(AB)}{P(A)}$ don't seem to help.

Example:

> In a horse race there are $3$ horses. $E12$
>   means horse $1$ finishes before horse $2$.
>   $E123$ means horse $1$ finishes before $2$,
>   which finishes before $3,$ etc.
>
> If **$P(E13)=2/3$** and **$P(E23)=1/2$** then
>   **$P(E123)=?$**

How can I go about solving this kind of problems?

Comment: @GeorgeS Please refrain from petty unnecessary edits on 4+ years old posts

Comment: Sure. I was checking out older questions and it was bothering me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **not** a conditional probability question.
Your particular example has insufficient information to solve it.
Here $E123$ is the event of the horses finishing in the order 1, 2, 3.
So (assuming the horses can't tie for a position)
$$P(E13)=P(E132)+P(E123)+P(E213),$$
$$P(E23)=P(E123)+P(E213)+P(E231)$$
and of course
$$1=P(E123)+P(E132)+P(E213)+P(E231)+P(E312)+P(E321).$$
Knowing $P(E13)$ and $P(E23)$ isn't enough to determine any one
of the $P(Eijk)$s.